# scaling Venn diagram in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to plot the Venn Diagram of intersection of 3 sets with the following function:

```
    library(VennDiagram)
    draw.triple.venn(10,5,4,2,3,1,1,ind=TRUE,scaled=TRUE).
```

In the Quartz window I receive 3 identical circles (all of the same size). Where did the scaling go? After several hours of trying, I am wondering if it is a bug or if maybe the previous settings of my plotting area are not allowing it ( i closed and reopened the Quartz window several times). The output value is:

```
    (polygon[GRID.polygon.1498], polygon[GRID.polygon.1499], polygon[GRID.polygon.1500], polygon[GRID.polygon.1501], polygon[GRID.polygon.1502], polygon[GRID.polygon.1503], text[GRID.text.1504], text[GRID.text.1505], text[GRID.text.1506], text[GRID.text.1507], text[GRID.text.1508], text[GRID.text.1509], text[GRID.text.1510], text[GRID.text.1511], text[GRID.text.1512])
```

Any help or tip would be appreciated. All the examples I see online are depicted already scaled.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, scaling only happens for *some* configurations. One example would be

```
draw.triple.venn(1,2,3,0,0,0,0)
```

On the other hand, looking at the source code of that function, there appears to be no relevant use of that parameter at all. And indeed, passing `scale=FALSE` to the above command still results in scaled circles.

So it looks like with the current source code, you have no control over scaling, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The scale parameter is being ignored in many cases.
Here is another example that is also not plotted to scale

```
venn.plot <- draw.triple.venn(1883,598,2151,218,221,611,95, c("AL", "RL", "R"),scale=TRUE)
```

I used this .jar instead:
http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/pjr/EulerVennCircles/EulerVennApplet.html